# Unable to call Rails Models inside Sidekiq worker class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm using the sidekiq scheduler gem to schedule and run tasks in the background.
The setup works fine and tasks get scheduled and executed correctly, however, if I want run methods from inside my rails models I can't. This is how I run sidekiq:

```
sidekiq -r ./app/workers/get_new_users.rb -e production
```

How can I get my get_new_users script to call methods in my models?

```
require 'sidekiq-scheduler'


class GetNewUsers
  include Sidekiq::Worker


  def perform
    puts User.find(1)
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'running methods from inside my models'?
If you're passing for instance id of a model to your worker, you should be able to instantiate you rmodels like:

User.find(id)

and call methods on it.

Comment: That's a typo I meant call instead of run :) 

When I call User.find(id) I get this error:

    NameError: uninitialized constant GetNewUsers::User

Comment: Can you show the code for the worker

Comment: Added to the main question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop the `-r` parameter and sidekiq will then load your rails environment (read: all your models and other things)

You can also drop `-e` (which will then be taken from `RAILS_ENV` env var, which should be set anyway).

And it's a good idea to run your binaries through bundler. So, your command becomes just this:

```
 bundle exec sidekiq
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, I put the -r switch when I added the scheduler gem in this came from the documentation.